# Using a date variable to calculate last working date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the sql table I have a column with dates in it. I want to work out the last working day for each of the dates.

Some of the dates are;

- 2016-05-05
- 2016-07-01
- 2016-03-05

I thought of using something similar to this

```
 SELECT DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

but not sure what I'd need to change.

Comment: What do you mean by "last working day"?

Comment: I personally do not fully understand what you want so an actual sample table with some output would be useful (along with your DBMS - which you should have tagged).  Is it as simple as using MAX()? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx

Comment: The last working day of the month. e.g last working day of last month 2016-06-30

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (DATEADD and GETDATE are product specific functions.)

Comment: Last day of the month, last *Friday* of the month, last non-[local-]Holiday weekday of the month...?

Comment: Last weekday of the month e.g. Thursday 30th June 2016

Comment: Your syntax suggests SQL Server - what version are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @FraserMunro That doesn't answer the question.  Are you using SQL Server 2012?  2008 R2?  2016?  Etc.

Comment: @Siyual I'm using 2008

Comment: Edit your question and enter desired output alongside each input. That's the best way to get proper answer without wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date datetime = '20160211'



SELECT dateadd(day,-day(dateadd(month,1,@DATE)), dateadd(month,1,@DATE) )  - 
        CASE WHEN 
            datediff(day,0,dateadd(day,
                                    -day(dateadd(month,1,@DATE)), 
                                    dateadd(month,1,@DATE))
                                                ) % 7 = 5 
            THEN 
                1 
                ELSE 
                0
            END -
        CASE WHEN 
            datediff(day,0,dateadd(day,
                                    -day(dateadd(month,1,@DATE)), 
                                    dateadd(month,1,@DATE))
                                    ) % 7 = 6 
            THEN 
                2 
                ELSE 
                0 
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work everyday:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = GETDATE();

--Last day of month
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-1
```

If you, like me, work from monday to friday:

```
--Last day from MON-FRI
--1-SUN, 2-MON, ..., 7-SAT
SELECT TOP 1 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-N
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)) T(N)
WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)+1,0)-N) IN (2,3,4,5,6)--From MON to FRI
ORDER BY N;
```

You can simply change your workdays.

If you would like to include holidays, you need additional table with that dates.

Answer (score 0):

This is direct from my SQL to you to find last Working day of current month. I had this on my Stored procedure.

```
 declare @dt datetime, 
        @lastDate datetime, 
        @lastWeekDay datetime
set @dt=getdate();
<-- if you want to find of specific month than in place of getdate() above write like '06/06/2016' -->
set @lastDate = (SELECT DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @dt) + 1,0)));
declare @dayOfWeek INT = (SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @lastDate) % 7);
set @lastWeekDay = (SELECT CASE WHEN @dayOfWeek = 5 THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @lastDate)
                           WHEN @dayOfWeek = 6 THEN DATEADD(dd, -2, @lastDate)
                           ELSE @lastDate END)
SELECT @lastWeekDay;
```